# Unity New Input System .started doesn't work but .performed works twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I'm creating a shooting angry birds style game with new input system.

I want to save the mouse position to a variable when the mouse is clicked and released.

Subscribing to the `.started` event doesn't work. Using `.performed`, it works with 1 click 2 times, once at the start and once after release.

When I try `.canceled` it doesn't work too.

```cs
    private void OnEnable()
    {
            controls.Gameplay.Shoot.started += _ => PlayerAimingStart();
            controls.Gameplay.Shoot.performed += _ => PlayerAimingPerformed();
    }
        private void PlayerAimingStart()
        {
            shootingPositionStart = controls.Gameplay.MousePosition.ReadValue<Vector2>(); shootingPositionStart.z = 0f;
        }
    
        private void PlayerAimingPerformed()
        {
            shootingPositionEnd = controls.Gameplay.MousePosition.ReadValue<Vector2>(); shootingPositionEnd.z = 0f;
            Vector3 force = shootingPositionStart - shootingPositionEnd;
            Vector3 clampedForce = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(force, maxDrag) * power;
            bulletGO.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(clampedForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

In the input action asset, under my gamplay action map and action, `Gameplay > Actions: Shoot/Left Button`

I had to add a press interaction on the right hand side
`Interactions > Press`

and set the trigger behavior to `Press And Release`.

Comment: This solved the same issue I was facing. Thanks for the answer!